# How can I list my containers / repos from Amazon ECS

Tags: aws-ecs

I thought this must be an easy task - show my repos/containers from ECS on the cmdline but I couldn't find anything: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/index.html#cli-aws-ecs

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**ECR**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/index.html) (Amazon Elastic Container Registry) for that:

- [describe-repositories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-repositories.html)
- [list-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/list-images.html)
- [describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-images.html)
- [batch-get-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/batch-get-image.html)

For containers ([**ECS**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/index.html#cli-aws-ecs)):

- [list-container-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-container-instances.html)
- [describe-container-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-container-instances.html)

Comment: OMG Thanks! Maybe I had not enough sleep last night.